# Querying a remote MSIDXS via T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, indexing-service

I think this question better fits here rather than ServerFault, but if I'm wrong, please correct me.

I have a system which has a database that also queries Windows Indexing Services. The queries are done via T-SQL using the OpenQuery(Linked_Server_Name, ...) function.
When the DB and the Indexing Services are on the same server, everything works perfectly.

Now I need to scale my system up, which means I'll have to separate the DB server from the Indexing Services server. The problem is, I couldn't find a way to remotely query the Indexing Services.

Did anyone succeed with a similar setup?
If no, what alternatives would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my company and I googled, that remote indexing is impossible. But we found a solution. Now we have one server with DB and another server with IIS and attachments which are indexed. The solution was to share attachments folder (or maybe whole disc) that DB server could see them. Unfortunatly, I changed position in the company and I don't have permissions anymore to connect to servers to check for configuration, so I can't write what and where exactly must be done.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ended up writing a web service as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It really does seem impossible to remote query MSIDXS. I ended up writing a web service that wraps the MSIDXS and is called remotely.
Performance aren't as good, though.